# Creating Work Shift Calendar to be used wit MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Greetings, I would like to ask on how do I create a work shift calendar to be used with MySQL database. What I am trying to achieve is that when user access my page on a specific date, the script will check work shift calendar on what is the shift on that date, and input into the database on the shift type.

The shift pattern is:
3 shifts: A, B, C.
Each shift work 4 days morning shift, then rest 2 days and work 4 days night shift, and repeat.

Appreciate if anyone can give me some advice on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a worker goes 18 days (4 + 2) * 3 before starting the cycle over again?

Comment: Workers work 4 days morning shift and then rest 2 days, then continue to night shift for 4 days then rest 2 days. This pattern shared by 3 shifts, thus, during either 1 of the shift in 2 rest days, it is covered by the other shift.

Comment: I'm still confused.  One worker only works two shifts?  How do you determine which workers work the 1st shift, the 2nd shift, and the 3rd shift?

Comment: There are 3 shifts, A, B and C. Each shift work in Continuous-Work-Week, which say, A morning for 4 days (starting 1st day), B night for 4 shift (starting 3rd day, since it's CWW), which C in rest days, and it continues. When A shift reached 3rd day morning, B already finish night entering rest day. Night shift continue by C shift 1st day. The pattern continue. Hope this can give you a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the standard work pattern for each worker mathematically.

Usually, there's a supervisor interface to override the standard work pattern.  People get sick, need time off for other reasons.

You would have the worker interface so a worker can see when she's working for the upcoming month.

The data that you'd want to store in the database for a work shift is worker id, timestamp for the start of the shift.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Now I have another question, is there any possibility that I can generate the complete whole year shift calendar, and then compare today's date to the generated shift calendar and look for information in it?

Comment: Yes, you can generate the shift calendar for any time period you wish.  But, as I said, people get sick and need time off for other reasons.  You want to save the generated shift calendar and allow a supervisor to change the work shifts when necessary.

Comment: Per your suggestion, what I am currently trying is to generate a table in the database consist the date from 1-Jan-2011 to 31-Dec-2011 with all shift pattern in it. Then, when I query from my webpage, the query result table (which is another table that stores worker information) will be generated by referring to the shift pattern. Still trying on that, wonder if it works.